# why jenkins has many folders for one job

Tags: jenkins

Today, one of my jenkins slave ran into disk problem. There are a lot of folders for one job.
e.g.

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Oct 11 06:23 Walle_play
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Sep 11 16:20 Walle_play@2
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Sep 11 19:23 Walle_play@3
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Oct  8 13:51 Walle_play@4
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Oct  8 13:51 Walle_play@5
drwxr-xr-x   7 jenkins jenkins  103 Oct  8 13:51 Walle_play@6
```

These folders use a lot of disk space. Could I delete them manually? What causes this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the whole structure..., not even the `PWD`... You want us to guess?

So here is my guess on the limited OP. The `@` is the default workspace separator used when a job is configured to build parallel/concurrently. As such, those are probably the workspace folders.

Workspace folders are safe to be deleted, provided you have a robust enough job configuration that recreates everything it needs for the workspace (SCM checkout, scripts, etc). End of guess.